# in which Activity am I?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there a way in which a piece of Java Android code can obtain some information - a PID of some sort - about in which Activity is this piece of code executing?

The point: I am writing an Android library. In order to support being called from multiple Activities at the same time, the library needs to somehow be able to tell that this call came from Activity 'A' and that one - from Activity 'B'.

(alternatively, I could make my users add an extra parameter to each library call - some sort of Activity PID - and detect the Activity in this way, but IMHO this makes for a clumsy API - I'd much rather avoid that)

Answer (score 0):

You know all your activities so you can check it via if statement like :

for kotlin :

```
class GetActivity(val activity : Activity)
{
if(activity is MainActivty)
{
//So you will know this is the main Activity
}

else if(activity is secondActivity )
{
// bla bla bla
}

}
```

Comment: I don't know all of my Activities. In fact, there are no 'my' Activities. All I know is the library code, which does not have any Activity and which will be called from various applications written by third parties, and at times it can be called by multiple Activities at once.

Answer (score 0):

StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

Then parse the array to find the callers of your method